# google speech to text not working correctly with very short audio (single words)

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

I'm testing google Speech-to-Text API with streaming audio as well as with wav files.
I'm using audio from telephony: 8000 sample rate, 8bits, mulaw encoding. The Google configuration is set appropriately.

When I test it with normal sequences, it returns a correct transcription.
However when I say a single word (especially a number), I'm very often obtaining no response from the api -> as if it would be no input. This occurrence happens for both streaming as well as batch transcription.

does anybody know why is this happening? how to fix it?

Comment: Is it possible for you to transcode to LINEAR16 or FlAC encoding ? The [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices) of Cloud Speech-to-Text API suggest the same.

Comment: Hi, consider accepting/upvoting the answer if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud Speech-to-Text API  [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/best-practices) suggest using a lossless codec like FLAC or LINEAR16. I verified with LINEAR16 and it works for single words which are digits. So the solution would be to transcode the audio.